# "Колумбова" как производная от слова "Колумб"

Tags: слова

> Станция "Площадь Победы" лежала перед нами, и я чувствовал себя Колумбом, достигшим Америки. Ну ладно, сбавил я, одним из членов Колумбова экипажа.

Что это за слово *Колумбова*? Это не прилагательное, потому что оно кончалось бы тогда на -ого

Comment: На -ого было бы "колумбийского" (colombian). На -ова - "Колумбова" (Columb's).

Comment: должно писаться с маленькой буквы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Колумбов** – это, конечно же, прилагательное, [*притяжательное прилагательное*](http://russkiyyazik.ru/721/) – разряд прилагательных, выражающих принадлежность чего-либо лицу или животному (отцовы сапоги, волчья нора), образуются с помощью суффиксов -ов(-ев), -ин, -ий. О значении и употреблении притяжательных прилагательных можно [почитать у Розенталя](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/58.htm#%D0%B7_04).

Comment: Может сочетание "Рождество Христово" - это тоже притяжательное прилагательное? И является ли по сути слово "Колумбов" устарелым?

Comment: @marmistrz - «Христово» – это тоже притяжательное прилагательное. Устаревшее ли оно, сказать точно не могу, но мне кажется, что все притяжательные прилагательные на -ов являются в некоторой мере устаревшими.

Answer (score 2):

Это все-таки прилагательное, просто родительный и дательный падеж в мужском и среднем роде у него **Колумбова** и **Колумбову**, соответственно.

В то же время притяжательные на **-ин** склоняются вполне «прилагательно»: **маминого**, **маминому**, а не **мамина*, **мамину*.

Объясняется это, видимо, тем, что с притяжательными прилагательными *-jь* в праславянском не сочеталось (что видно по исходным формам), поэтому склонение по образцу прилагательных возникло позже, по аналогии, которая осталась неполной. По тому, как ведут себя притяжательные прилагательные в польском, сложно об этом догадаться — однако же, например, в чешском (где склонение очень консервативно) «существительных» окончаний гораздо больше, чем в русском:

> Kolumbov**a** mořsk**á** výprav**a**  *(экспедиция)*
>
> Kolumbov**y** mořsk**é** výprav**y**
>
> Kolumbov**ě** mořsk**é** výprav**ě**
>
> o Kolumbov**ě** slavn**ém** objev**u** *(открытии)*

Comment: Формы _мамина, мамину_ вполне допустимы.  https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD

Comment: @YellowSky я что-то никогда не встречал.

Comment: Розенталь пишет: «Возможны варианты окончаний в родительном и дательном падежах мужского и среднего рода прилагательных на -ин; ср.: _возле дедушкина дома – возле дедушкиного дома_; _к соседкину сыну – к соседкиному сыну_. Краткие формы (с окончаниями -а, -у) являются устарелыми и вытесняются формами с полным окончанием (-ого, -ому).» И тем не менее, они возможны.

Comment: @YellowSky Розенталь пишет, а я, повторюсь, не встречал никогда.

Comment: И я не встречал, но мир полон чудес, и лишь малая их толика нам открыта. ;)

Comment: Определённо встречал такую форму. На слух казалось как-то "по-деревенски", но специально сверился с Зализняком - даётся как второй вариант, но без дополнительных пометок. В общем, считать этот вариант устаревшим или каким ещё, но он в любом случае допустим. Кстати, на wiktionary ляп в Дт. ср.р. - должно быть так же как и м.р.